# Resize Highcharts when sidemenu is toggled

Tags: javascript, html, css, highcharts

How can I dynamically change the size of a Highcharts chart when a Bootstrap sidemenu is toggled? The chart resizes fine when the window size changes, but the sidemenu toggling provides more room on the page, and the chart width needs to expand to cover that room. I've tried using jQuery selectors to apply a change, but nothing works. Any ideas?

Comment: How about `Chart.reflow`? http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Chart.reflow

Comment: Perfect, thanks a ton!